# How can i pass my values in e-mail activation link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I wrote some codes in deneme.aspx it works but it does not pass the variables(Id(levent) and userName(levent)) to activateUser.aspx. how can i do it?

```
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
        var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("bilkentliaslan@windowslive.com");
        mail.To.Add("levent_kalay@hotmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string htmlBody;
        htmlBody = string.Format("<a href='http://localhost:15534/ActivateUser.aspx?userName{0}&Id={1}'>Activate {0} </a>", "levent", "levent");
        mail.Body = htmlBody;

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("bilkentliaslan@windowslive.com", "mypassword");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Then, After clicking the confirmation link, It goes to ActivateUser.aspx in there

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["Id"]))
        {
            // We do not have the userId. Redirect some where
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            // We have a userId.
            try
            {
                DBConnection db = new DBConnection();
                string username= Request.Params["userName"];
                bool res =     db.CheckLogin(Request.Params["userName"],Request.Params["Id"]);
                if (res)
                {
                    Session["LetLogin"] = "ok";


                    Session["User_Name"] = Request.Params["userName"];
                    Response.Redirect("WebForm4.aspx",true);
                }


            }
            catch
            {
                // Error. Redirect some where
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
        }
        // We should never reach here. Just in case redirect some where
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend taking out the email addresses and just putting in junk data

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your generated URL;

```
ActivateUser.aspx?    userName{0}&Id={1}
```

...is missing an equals sign between 'userName' and 'levent'.